# WCF: Minimum client configuration required

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

What is the absolute minimum configuration required for a client to consume a WCF service?

Maybe I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem logical to restate a bunch of settings values on the client that should really be defined and controlled by the service on the server.  A good example is MaxBytesPerRead.  But what about security and other settings?

It seems to me that the client should only need to know the ABC's (endpoint address, binding type and contract) then let the server determine the rest.  Am I off-base?

Comment: When you say minimum configuration, are you saying minimum *.config configuration or all configuration, including in-code configuration?  Also, what version of .Net are you using?  .Net 4 adds lots of defaults which cuts down on the needed config.

Comment: I was thinking XML configuration but if there are in-code requirements, I'd like to know that too.  I'm actually supporting .NET 3.5 and 4.0 so knowing 3.5 then what's changed in 4 would be ideal.

Comment: What type of binding is the server?  Soap+Http? Rest? Tcp?

Comment: If you have a WCF REST service: just a HTTP enabled web browser, that's all (and the proper URL's). If you use a WCF SOAP service : a valid SOAP client capable of calling WCF:

Comment: @Brook: Does it really matter except that the client has to specify the right one (the B in ABC)?

Comment: The server can not determine the rest.  Whoever is hosting the client may determine that the max file size that server can accept is much smaller than the max file size that the server can spit out.  The client's configuration is its own business.  It helps if it matches the server, but WCF shouldn't REQUIRE it to.

Comment: That's a good point. Those settings are for the client side of the channel and aren't telling the server how to behave which is why I didn't believe they were required (as long as we accept the defaults).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166871/WCF-Services-with-Zero-Config-on-both-the-Host-and.aspx?display=Print), but keep in mind that zero config has limitations.  For example, as Terry said, if it sees "http", it's going to use the basicHttpBinding, so if you're using REST it will likely break.

If you are using `basicHttp` (or another zero-config capable binding) then I'd say this is the minimum configuration.

This does NOT copy down all the various settings such as `MaxBytesPerRead` to the client.  You'll still have to code or configure those yourself.

Comment: It looks like this confirms that all we need is the ABCs if we are willing to accept the default values. And, if not, we only need to set the exceptions and not everything.